# "This site can’t be reached" after FileSizeLimitExceededException error

Tags: java, servlets

In my servlet (Apache Tomcat v9.0) I have added this annotation in order to limit the size of the uploaded file:

```
@MultipartConfig(location = "/tmp", fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024, maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50, maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100)
```

This works but when I try to upload a large file, in the browser I see this error message:

> "This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset."

In browser's devTools I am getting this status `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

In the `web.xml` file I have added:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and in the servlet I have put the statements inside `try-catch`

```
try{
  //get files from the user
}catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e);
}

response.sendRedirect("/mypage.jsp");
```

and in the logs I am getting the following message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field files exceeds its maximum permitted size of 52428800 bytes.
```

What am I missing here? Why I am not see my jsp page (mypage.jsp or error404.jsp, error405.jsp) and I am getting this error in the browser?

Comment: What is the response status code? Look in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: DevTools gives the following status: `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: Did it give a status code number? 500 ? 200 ?

Comment: No, I am not getting 200,400,500 code. Instead I get the above message.

Comment: Did you try answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573450/how-to-handle-maxuploadsizeexceededexception-maximum-upload-in-servlet    That answer put the response.sendError line inside the catch block.